# Is it possible to remove the default Microsoft Pinyin Simplefast on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, input-languages

The option to remove is greyed out in the language settings. Is there any way to uninstall this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I just figured this out!

1. Go to Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language
2. Remove the Chinese language altogether
3. Install your other languages directly.
   3.a If you're using Sogou, go to 输入法管理器, uncheck all languages except English, and check set it as default, press OK
   3.b Launch 输入法管理器 again, check both English and Chinese, save as default, press OK.

Now you should have only English and the selected Chinese input method!

Hope this helps.